# UITextView (in UITableViewCell) collapse itself when run on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a `UITableView` with a **empty** `UITextView` (and other objects, like `UILabel`) inside. I'm using auto layout, and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

When I run it on the simulator the `textView` collapse itself. Meaning, its height becomes like 1 px or something. The other `views`, like the `label` stays the right size.

Is there a way of fixing the `textView` so that it wouldn't collapse itself when I run it on the simulator?

(Note: the `textViews` height will be dynamic.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add auto layout constraint to set a "magic number" for the height of the textView.

Comment: Is there another way? I did think of that, but the textView will change heights dynamically.

Comment: In that case you might want to set a "height is greater than x" constraint rather than "equal to". @Jounson